# Where is Google Chrome Crash Dump Located?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I am going Google Chrome, on Windows XP. Sometimes it crashed, and I want to know where the crash dump is located, just for fun.

Answer (score 29):

There is no longer an 'under the hood' option anymore and hence the above answer is obsolete and no longer of any use.  With a newer version of chrome you need to enable crash logs by going to

1. settings/privacy
2. enabling: Automatically send usage statistics and crash reports to Google.
3. After that you can check your crash logs here: `chrome://crashes/`

Comment: Correct answer here and was a great help.  Thank you Ryan.

Comment: in chrome://crashes there is only a list, not the crash dump... how to read these?

Comment: The last dump files themselves are stored under `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Crashpad\reports`, you don't even need to enable reporting...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot see crash dumps / logs unless you've started chrome with the

`--enable-logging --v=1` (in Linux)

flag. Otherwise the only thing you see will be the crashID.

Please refer to [this page](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) for more information regarding chrome and debuging/logging.

#### Note

Though I'd be a happy person if someone proved me wrong and showed a way for retrieving a crashdump / log based on crashID ( f5bf0cf6f184b9d2 )

Comment: [It doesn’t work for 64 bits specific bugs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37231711/2284570).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the dmp file and analyze it following these directions:
http://www.chromium.org/developers/decoding-crash-dumps

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.