# Google Chrome is crashing when I open it

Tags: google-chrome

My Google Chrome keeps crashing all the time when I open it. The following screens appear when I open it:

[image]

[image]

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall Google Chrome, but it didn't work. I have tried a fix that I found on a Google webpage where I deleted the profile and recreated it, but that did not work either.

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit and Google Chrome 31.0.1650.57.

Comment: We need more information.  What operating system?  What version of Chrome are you using?  Have you installed all security updates to all programs like ( Adobe Flash, Java, ect ).  What does the crash log file contain? We would only be guessing with the supplied screenshots.

Comment: Where do i find the crash log?

Comment: @Inkey http://superuser.com/questions/624/where-is-google-chrome-crash-dump-located Once you've got the dump file, feel free to post it  in your question if you can't determine the issue yourself.

Comment: Try deleting chrome from the Windows registry too after uninstalling it. I've been through such scenarios with software before and this typically rectifies the issue.

Comment: You can try using another version of Chrome (Beta or Canary) temporarily, and retry stable once another version has been released.